# How to ignore some file in SVN using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have strange question. I'm working on Linux Mint 16 (Petra) and using SVN with Eclipse. IN SVN I have many website like for example stackoverflow.com (name of project in SVN). In this project (name would you like) I have all files from FTP even cache file bcs I test my website on localhost. When I import this project everything is good. I changed a few file. At the end, when I want synchronize with SVN I have for example 1k files. Many of then are cache, tpl.php or .sr.

In eclipse Preferences >Team > Ignored Resources I add all of them. In terminal I want do the same but I couldn't for example few command and error:

```
G41MT-S2P ~ # svn propset svn:ignore cache .
svn: E155007: '/root' not a working copy
```

Whatever I do nothing happend. I red a few article on web where everyone said that svn:ignore in eclipse work only then when this file is not in SVN. My example is different because I need this file in SVN and in localhost.

Sorry for my language. 
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

1. `svn:ignore` property affects only unversioned items in your working copy,
2. The command-line `svn propset` must be run against a working copy. You run it against some folder which is not a working copy therefore you get the error.
3. It's common practice to set `svn:ignore` and `svn:global-ignore` when you put a project to Subversion. I.e. you know that your working copy will have some, say A, B, C, items that must not be in a repository so you setup Subversion to ignore these A B C items at the very beginning.

Read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html).

Comment: what you mean 'working copy" I run this command in folder where I have SVN.

Comment: run `svn st -v` against this folder and see the result. Do you get any error?

Comment: the same error. So what is it this working copy. I thought that is a main folder SVN

Comment: @user3888895 you have to learn how to use version-control and `svn` in general. Please read SVNBook, here is the starter chapter http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.initial.html. Read it and proceed to Basic Work Cycle.